# Why is the dust gathering this way?

Tags: nature

[image]I bought a clock from the store that has no battery inside. Completely new. This was inside the walls of the cheap clock. I was completely confused as stated above… it wipes off with your finger. The temperature this clock has been is room temperature by the way. I am really intrigued about what it is. It’s dust alright, wipes off with finger but why is it gathering like a snowflake or lightning effect?

[image]

These appear to be the same phenomena as asked about in ["Reason for strange "canyons" of dust on the cooling platform"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80995/145491), but unlike the examples shown there,  in this case there are no circular spots or other features for the dust to gather, nor any fans creating airflow.

Comment: I can't really understand the figure. What are we looking at? Could you add another photo, or some details to the description?

Comment: Maybe the factory was dusty?

Comment: If the dust is gathering on a plastic surface this might be because the surface has acquired an electric charge, perhaps by rubbing against other insulators.

Comment: i've seen this in a film! have you checked morse or binary? :)

Comment: This is the circular wall inside the clock. There’s nothing exerting force on this object, simply the dust has gathered forming sort of branches that seem like snowflakes or lightning shaped. How did that happen? Is it bacteria that caused this formation in the dust? The surface which is on is smooth.